# Spring @RequestParam with class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I use `Spring` and `Hiberate` to create simply web service. In Controller i have long list of args from form.

My Controller

```
 @RequestMapping( value="/addAccount", method=RequestMethod.POST )
public String addAccoundPOST( @RequestParam( value = "username" )   String username,
                              @RequestParam( value = "password" )   String password,
                              @RequestParam( value = "email" )      String email,
                              @RequestParam( value = "name" )       String name, 
                              @RequestParam( value = "surname" )    String surname,
                              @RequestParam( value = "birth_date" ) String birth_date, 
                              @RequestParam( value = "place" )      String place,
                              @RequestParam( value = "province" )   String province,
                              @RequestParam( value = "motorcycle" ) String motorcycle,
                              @RequestParam( value = "tel" )        String tel ) 
{
    User user = new User();

    if( username != null && username.length() >= 4 )
        user.setUsername( username );

    if( password != null && password.length() >= 4 )
        user.setPassword( password );

    // and more, and more, and mode....

    return "addAccount";
}
```

Part of User class:

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "users", catalog = "dbjadenazlot" )
public class User implements Serializable {
private int uid;

private String ...;
/* --------------------------------- GET ------------------------------ */

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column( name = "uid", unique = true, nullable = false )
public int getUID()             
    { return uid;}

@Column( name = "name", length = 45 )
public String getName()         
    { return name; }
// setters and rest code.. 
}
```

Is it possible to convert my arguments from POST request to class? If it's possible, what is required?

```
 @RequestMapping( value="/addAccount", method=RequestMethod.POST )
public String addAccoundPOST( @RequestParam( value = "user") User user ) 
{

    return "addAccount";
}
```

How can i write shorten code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, in your first example,

```
if( username != null && username.length() >= 4 )
```

checking for `null` is not necessary. Spring will return a 400 status code, if a `@RequestParam` cannot be resolved.

> it is possible to convert my arguments from POST request to class? If it's possible, what is required?

Yes, create a class, possibly your `User` class, which has fields that share the same name as the request parameters. Make your handler method accept a parameter of that class.

```
public String addAccoundPOST( @ModelAttribute User user )
```

If you want to validate it, just add `@Valid`.

```
public String addAccoundPOST( @Valid @ModelAttribute User user )
```

Comment: What if one of paramether is date, need i some annotations or something ?

Comment: @kris14an Look into `@DateTimeFormat`.

Comment: A great source for seeing what's possible with Spring MVC regarding what you are trying to do can be found in the Spring documentation http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html