# Spring @RequestParam - Mixing named params and Map<String,String> params

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm writing a Spring Boot application which receives parameters via REST endpoint and forwards them to another system. The received params contain some known fields but may also contain multiple variable fields starting with `filter` followed by an undefined name:

`example.com?id=1&name=foo&filter1=2&filterA=B&[...]&filterWhatever=something`

As you can see there are params `id` and `name`, and multiple params starting with `filter`. When calling the target system, I need to remove `filter` from the param keys and use everything after that as key:

`targetsystem.com?id=1&name=foo&1=2&A=B&[...]&whatever=something` (no more filter in keys)

This itself is not a problem, I can just just `@RequestParam Map<String, String> params`, stream/loop the params and modify as I want. But using Swagger as API documentation tool, I want to list all known parameters, so clients can see what is actually supported.

I tried mixing named params and catch-all params, but it doesn't recognize a handler:

`myEndpoint(final @RequestParam String id, final @RequestParam String name, final @RequestParam Map<String, String> remainingParams)`

Is it possible to map specific params and catch everything else in `Map<String,String>`? Or are there other possiblities, like mapping all params starting with `filter` using regex pattern?

Unfortunately I can't change source and target systems.

Comment: Try `@RequestMapping
public String books(@RequestParam Map<String, String> requestParams,
                        ){
  
}`

Comment: Oh my, thank you, that actually works! Putting `Map<String,String> params` in front and the known ones after that. I always tried it the other way around...
Please add it as answer so I can accept.

Comment: I added, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
@RequestMapping
public String books(@RequestParam Map<String, String> requestParams, Other params)
{ 
     //Your code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your *only* concern with using a generic map is simply Swagger being accurate, why not just add the `@ApiImplicitParams` [annotation](https://www.atechref.com/blog/spring-boot/swagger-2-apioperation-apiimplicitparams-usage/) to your endpoint? This would let you specify which params are required in your Swagger output:

```
@ApiImplicitParams(value = {
   @ApiImplicitParam(name = "name", type = "String", required = true, paramType = "query"),
   @ApiImplicitParam(name = "id", type = "String", required = true, paramType = "query")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a class, e.g.

```
@Data
public class Paramss {

    @NotNull
    private String a;
    private String b;
}
```

and then

```
@GetMapping
public Object params( @Valid @ModelAttribute Paramss params ) {
    return params;
}
```

See also: [Spring @RequestParam with class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22441136/spring-requestparam-with-class)

Comment: I don't see how that solves the problem with `0..n` params starting with prefix `filter` but an unknown variable name afterwards: `filterFoo=bar&filterA=B&filter1=2`. I tried to make this more clear in the description.

Comment: If you don't know statically (at compile time) the names of your parameters then how can you expose them in Swagger? You'll have to do it programatically, an write a comment in Swagger for using those dynamic parameters...

Comment: That's exactly my problem. I want to expose the known parameters in Swagger and have a generic field to map the dynamic ones.